# Netowork Broadcast Receiver not working for Android N

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-7.0-nougat

I have a Broadcast Receiver for connectivity changes and it works fine for all the devices running below android N but its not working on android N. I cannot find any thing relevant regarding this whether they changes something in N or not. DO anyone has any idea why this is happening?

**MANIFEST FILE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.admin.movies">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<application
    android:name=".MovieSingleton"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver
        android:name=".NetworkBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="false"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Here is my broadcast receiver

```
public class NetworkBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String TAG = NetworkBroadcastReceiver.class.getSimpleName();

public NetworkBroadcastReceiver() {

}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: network change");
    if(isOnline(context)){
        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: connected");
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: not connected");
    }
}


public boolean isOnline(Context mContext) {
    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
            mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected());
}
```

}

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/background-optimization.html and https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#bg-opt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since many apps register to receive this broadcast, a single network switch can cause them all to wake up and process the broadcast at once.

In Android Nougat, You have to register your BroadcastReceiver with Context.registerReceiver().

This change is part of Android 7.0 background optimizations and performance improvements.